# Property does not exist on type in computed function

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I new to TypeScript. The following code would work on JavaScript with no problems, but it's not compiling here.

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      data: [
        'Angular',
        'Angular 2',
        'Aurelia',
        'Backbone',
        'Ember',
        'jQuery',
        'Meteor',
        'Node.js',
        'Polymer',
        'React',
        'RxJS',
        'Vue.js'
      ],
      name: "",
      selected: null,
      hasVariationRadio: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredDataArray(): [] {
      return this.data.filter((option: string) => { // This is where the error appears
        return option
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0 // Also here.
      })
    }
  }
};
```

I'm getting the following error:
`Property 'name' does not exist on type '{ filteredDataArray(): []; }'.`

As mentioned [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html), `strict` is set to `true` inside compilerOptions in `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you mention in my setup (Vue CLI project w/TypeScript option selected). I get a different error: `Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[]'`, but setting the return type of `filteredDataArray()` to `string[]` resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this code in the console, it doesn't seem to be correct after all.

When you reference `this` inside `computed.filteredDataArray`, `this` is the `computed` object, not the whole thing.

Moving `filteredDataArray` one level higher makes it work:

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            data: [
                'Angular',
                'Angular 2',
                'Aurelia',
                'Backbone',
                'Ember',
                'jQuery',
                'Meteor',
                'Node.js',
                'Polymer',
                'React',
                'RxJS',
                'Vue.js'
            ],
            name: "",
            selected: null,
            hasVariationRadio: ""
        };
    },
    filteredDataArray() {
        return this.data().data.filter((option: string) => {
            return option
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(this.data().name.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: The code on the question works when the lang is set to JavaScript without a problem, after removing TypeScript specific return types. It is inside a Vue component, if that helps.

Comment: @Karol The code in question defines a [Vue component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), where `filteredDataArray` is a [computed prop](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).